# VBA Excel - How to enable editing format in a range in a protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a protected sheet while not allowing to select locked cells (only range that I want to format) while allowing a change of format of range("B22:M46"). Only the format

In other words, there will be a range where you can change only format of cells and all the other cells will be locked and user will not be able to select these cells.

I know how to protect sheet, how to unlock range and even how to enable selection, but I can't put it all together

Is this even possible? Thank you

Comment: have you tried the `userinterfaceonly` property on protect? "True to protect the user interface, but not macros. If this argument is omitted, protection applies both to macros and to the user interface"

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the interface, using the recorder gave me an answer:

```
With mySheet
    .Protect ...., AllowFormattingCells:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With
```

Comment: ok but how can I include range, where it is allowed to make format changes? which means that selecting is also allowed. I guess it is needed to allow selecting so you can edit format. Maybe I just do not understand, sorry I am a noob

Comment: Use Format cells: protected = False